C# Generic Child Parent Child Relationship
I am trying to create a list of typed objects for a project but realized that I'm having trouble creating a new list of parent typed objects and populating it with a list of child typed objects.
The use case is I will later instantiate the child typed objects and each one will preform their own task
This is basic example if the failure
public class test
{
    public interface IParent { }
    public partial class parent
    {
        public void Run() { }
    }
    public class child : parent, IParent 
    {
        public new void Run() { }
    }
    public class box<T> where T : parent, new()
    {
        //public static implicit operator box<T>(box<child> v) => v;
        public box()
        {
            new T().Run();
        }
    }

    test()
    {
        box<parent> box = new box<child>();
    }
}

I am getting the error
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxx.test.box<xxx.test.child>' to 'xxx.test.box<xxx.test.parent>'

I found some code examples of implicit conversion (commented), but I'm not sure how to convert box to box there either.
Would appreciate some guidance.

Class names should begin in upper case, so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lower case.

Don't use: public new void Run() { }. Instead make the method virtual in base class and override it.

Instead of implicit operator, you can introduce simple interface with generic covariant (out) parameter:
public interface IBox<out T>
{
    public T BoxedInstance { get; }
    public void Unpack();
}

And make Box implement that interface with providing required generic constraints. Include naming style "fix" (as @Progman noticed) and @Poul Bak suggestion for new keyword replacement, and result code may look like:
public class Box<T> : IBox<T> where T : IParent, new()
{
    public T BoxedInstance { get; }
    public Box() => BoxedInstance = new T();
    public void Unpack() => BoxedInstance.Run();
}

public interface IParent
{
    public void Run();
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
     // As Poul Bak suggested in comments, use "virtual" keyword
     // to be able to override it in child classes
     public virtual void Run() => Console.WriteLine("Parent Run");
}

public class Child : Parent
{
     // As Poul Bak suggested in comments, using "override" keyword
     // allows you to reimplement method behaviour in child class
     public override void Run() => Console.WriteLine("Child Run");
}


Now you're able to assign "boxed child" object as "boxed parent" through interface:
IBox<Parent> parentBox = new Box<Child>();
parentBox.Unpack(); // Outputs "Child Run" to console

More about covariance and related stuff you can find in documentation or just search through StackOverflow - here's also many posts and answers about that (like this).

Very nice answer. I realize that interface syntax wrt member accessibility has expanded but I don't believe the members of your interfaces should be explicitly marked public in this context. I realize this is just a matter of convention.

How can I use this, but also DI variables into the child class?  It seems it only allows you to have parameterless constructors.

@Eugene, yes, new() constraint requires class (or its child) which implements IParent have a parameterless constuctor. There are different ways how to change it with respect to DI, depends on your context. Create another post, provide code samples, will try discuss.
